# Computing the nth number of the fibonacci sequence, where n is entered at command line

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, fibonacci

I want to write a program to compute the nth number of the fibonnacci sequence, which i had done using printf and scanf. But I was hoping to change my program so that the sequence number is entered at the command line rather than entered when prompted by the program. This is what i've come up with. It compiles, but then it crashes when i run it... not sure why. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

This is a program to compute the nth number of the fibonnacci code using iteration. I have written it as such: 
You must enter the number of the sequence you wish to compute at the command line argv[1]. The program then takes this command line
argument and uses it in the while loop, and also prints this number.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main( int argc, char**argv ) {
int fib[3] = {0,1};
int counter = 0;
  printf("The %dth Fibonacci number is:\n", atoi(argv[1]));
while ( counter < atoi(argv[1]) ) {

    fib[2] = fib[0] + fib[1];
    fib[0] = fib[1];
    fib[1] = fib[2];
    counter++;
}
printf("%d\n", fib[0]);
getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. How come I can never get all my code in one blue box to make it look decent!

Comment: Use the Ctrl-K formatting option for code text.

Comment: Ok, will do from now on thanks!

Comment: you're initialzing the array to have just 3 elements?

Comment: are you giving it a command line option?

Comment: Yes I want to be able to enter which fibonacci number i want to print out at the command line

Comment: @Laura Boyle - What are the command line arguments you are passing ?

Comment: Yeah, i'm giving command line arguments and I also changed the code to print a warning when no argument is given which works, but when i enter a number at the command line it crashes and tells me there is a segmentation fault

Answer (score 4):

Check if the user actually passed an argument:

```
int main( int argc, char**argv ) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s number\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    ...
}
```

If he didn't, `argv[1]` is null, and you'll crash

Comment: Actually, I tried it again with this, made sure to enter a positive integer at the command line, and i'm still getting a segmentation fault

Comment: @Laura Boyle: Post updated code, and the command you execute.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>                                               int main( int argc, char**argv ){ if (argc < 3) { printf("ERROR! Usage: '%s' n, Where n is a positive integer", argv[2]); getchar(); return 1; } else { int fib[2] = {0,1}; int counter = 0; printf("The %dth Fibonacci number is:\n", (argv[3])); while ( counter < atoi(argv[3]) ) { fib[2] = fib[0] + fib[1]; fib[0] = fib[1]; fib[1] = fib[2]; counter++; } printf("%d\n", fib[0]); } getchar(); return 0; } `

Comment: You're printing argv[2] in your error check - you mean argv[0]. Also, you're using argv[3] without checking that argc is at least 4. argc is *count* of arguments, if argc is 3, argv[0]..[2] is valid.

Answer (score 3):

The program should check if a command line argument is present:

```
if (argc < 2)
{
    printf ("usage:  %s n\n  where n is a positive integer\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
}
```

If no argument is supplied, it will probably crash.

= = = = = edit = = = = =

I don't see any cause for a crash once the bug above is fixed.  This works okay:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, char**argv )
{
        int fib[3] = {0,1};
        int counter = 0;
        if (argc < 2)
        {
                printf ("usage: %s number\n", argv[0]);
                return 1;
        }

        printf("The %dth Fibonacci number is:\n", atoi(argv[1]));
        while ( counter < atoi(argv[1]) )
        {

                fib[2] = fib[0] + fib[1];
                fib[0] = fib[1];
                fib[1] = fib[2];
                counter++;
        }
        printf("%d\n", fib[0]);
        return 0;
}


[wally@zenetfedora ~]$ ./a.out 
usage: ./a.out number
[wally@zenetfedora ~]$ ./a.out 3
The 3th Fibonacci number is:
2
[wally@zenetfedora ~]$ ./a.out 4
The 4th Fibonacci number is:
3
[wally@zenetfedora ~]$ ./a.out 5
The 5th Fibonacci number is:
5
[wally@zenetfedora ~]$ ./a.out 6
The 6th Fibonacci number is:
8
[wally@zenetfedora ~]$ ./a.out 7
The 7th Fibonacci number is:
13
[wally@zenetfedora ~]$ ./a.out 8
The 8th Fibonacci number is:
21
[wally@zenetfedora ~]$ ./a.out 9
The 9th Fibonacci number is:
34
[wally@zenetfedora ~]$ ./a.out 10
The 10th Fibonacci number is:
55
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this but still when I enter a positive integer (3 say) It tells me I have a segmentation fault(core dumped). I know what a segmentation fault is, but don't understand the "core dumped" bit.

Comment: "Core dumped" means the memory contents of your process was (or could have been) written to disk for later analysis.  Many, if not most, Linux distributions provide a default resource limit which prevents the core file from being written (rendering the message misleading):  type `ulimit -a` to see the settings:  a "core file size" of zero is typical.  To enable it, try something like `ulimit -c 5000` which gives a 5 megabyte limit.

Answer (score 0):

What number did you test it with? Because an int won't be able to hold anything higher than the ~50th Fibonacci number. I had to do something like this in my Algorithms class and we had to find the 239th Fibonacci number which was `64202014863723094126901777428873111802307548623680`
Which is something an int nor a long can hold correctly.I don't think that would make it crash but just giving a heads up if you need to find a large Fibonacci number.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int c,char *v[])

{

int *numberOfTerms;

int x,y,z,i,count;

if(c==1)

{

printf("provide number of terms as command line argument");

return 0;

}

numberOfTerms=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

*numberOfTerms=atoi(v[1]);

x=0;

y=1;

if(*numberOfTerms==0) return 0;

if(*numberOfTerms<=2)

{

for(i=0;i<*numberOfTerms;i++) printf("%d\n",i);

return 0;

}

printf("%d\n",x);

printf("%d\n",y);

count=2;

while(count<*numberOfTerms)

{

z=x+y;

printf("%d\n",z);

x=y;

y=z;

count++;

}

}
```

Comment: Some explanations to go along with the code would be very much appreciated I think

Comment: this is a program to print the fibonacci series upto to n terms, provided by the user as command line argument.. the number is stored in an char[].. so it is need to be converted to int.. for this i have used a predefined funtion "atoi".. and for this stdlib must be included

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the series upto a certain number specified as command line argument, then go for this program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int c,char *v[])
{
    int *number;
    int x,y,z;
    if(c==1)
    {
        printf("provide number upto which febonacci is to be printed (greater than 2)");
        return 0;
    }
    number=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *number=atoi(v[1]);
    x=0;
    y=1;
    printf("%d\n",x);
    printf("%d\n",y);
    z=x+y;
    while(z<=*number)
    {
        printf("%d\n",z);
        x=y;
        y=z;
        z=x+y;
    }
}
```